# Porting Python 2x to 3x

Tags: python-3.7

i'm trying to port script from python 2 to 3 version.

I'm new to python so I cannot figure out how to translate it:

```
cmd = filter(None, [
    '/usr/bin/cmake',
    lists_directory,
    '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=' + args.prefix,
    '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=' + ('Debug' if args.debug else 'Release'),
    '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=' + args.toolchain,
    '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=' + ('1' if args.shared else '0'),
    '-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=' + '/usr/ninja/ninja-1.7.2/bin/ninja' if args.generator == 'Ninja' else None,
    '-DAPP_MAX_LINKER_JOBS=' + str(args.linker_jobs) if args.linker_jobs else None,
    '-G', args.generator,
])

cmd += args.other
```

This gives the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'filter' and 'list
```

How port it to Python 3? I didn't find the answer yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 `filter` return a generator object. Use `list()` to convert it to a list object.

**Ex:**

```
cmd = list(filter(None, [
    '/usr/bin/cmake',
    lists_directory,
    '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=' + args.prefix,
    '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=' + ('Debug' if args.debug else 'Release'),
    '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=' + args.toolchain,
    '-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=' + ('1' if args.shared else '0'),
    '-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=' + '/usr/ninja/ninja-1.7.2/bin/ninja' if args.generator == 'Ninja' else None,
    '-DAPP_MAX_LINKER_JOBS=' + str(args.linker_jobs) if args.linker_jobs else None,
    '-G', args.generator,
]))

cmd += args.other
```